# How do I center align all my HTML Tables, and how do I keep all the tables the same width?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having an issue where as I want to have all the tables to be center aligned just like the 'Ruby Table' but I don't know how to do this.

Also you may notice that some tables are wider than others, What CSS rule can I implement to change the width of the whole table to my liking so all the tables can be the same width?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Personal Bests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <main>

   <div id="section">
      <article>
        <h2>FireFalcons1 Best Times</h2>
     <p>
    Below you will find all of my best times on Time Trials Max Speed (100%) and Story Mode (100%)
    </p>
    <p class="TA">
    TIME ATTACK - MAX SPEED (100%)
      </article>
    </div>

<!--Ruby HMTL Table-->

<table class="rubyTable">
  <tr>
    <th class="rubyHeader" colspan="6">Ruby Cup</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Course</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Time</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Best Lap</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Machine</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Replay</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Rank</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rubyTracks">Mute City<br>- Twist Road - </td>
    <td class="rubyData">53"699</td>
    <td class="rubyData">15"645</td>
    <td class="rubyData">Quick Star - G4</td>
    <td class="rubyData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="rubyData">46th</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rubyTracks">   Aeropolis<br>   - Multiplex - </td>
    <td class="rubyData">1'50"727</td>
    <td class="rubyData">33"825</td>
    <td class="rubyData">Fat Shark</td>
    <td class="rubyData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="rubyData">45th</td>
  </tr>
  </table>


<!--Sapphire HMTL Table-->

  <table class="sapphireTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="sapphireHeader" colspan="6">Sapphire Cup</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sapphireTitles">Course</td>
    <td class="sapphireTitles">Time</td>
    <td class="sapphireTitles">Best Lap</td>
    <td class="sapphireTitles">Machine</td>
    <td class="sapphireTitles">Replay</td>
    <td class="sapphireTitles">Rank</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sapphireTracks"> Mute City <br> - Serial Gaps - </td>
    <td class="sapphireData">56"747</td>
    <td class="sapphireData">16"988</td>
    <td class="sapphireData">Gallant Star - G4</td>
    <td class="sapphireData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="sapphireData">26th</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="axTracks">Mute City<br>- Sonic Oval - </td>
    <td class="axData">40"936</td>
    <td class="axData">11"550</td>
    <td class="axData">Quick Star - G4</td>
    <td class="axData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="axData">16th</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

<!--Emerald HMTL Table-->

  <table class="emeraldTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="emeraldHeader" colspan="6">Emerald Cup </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="emeraldTracks">Casino Palace<br>- Double Branches -</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">2'31"256</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">47"016</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">Gallant Star - G4</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">33rd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="emeraldTracks">Lightning<br>- Loop Cross - </td>
    <td class="emeraldData">2'23"611</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">45"672</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">Fat Shark</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">41st</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="emeraldTracks">Big Blue <br>- Ordeal - </td>
    <td class="emeraldData">2"18"024</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">40"999</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">Gallant Star - G4</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="emeraldData">32nd</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<!--Diamond HMTL Table-->
  <table class="diamondTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="diamondHeader" colspan="6">Diamond Cup </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="diamondTitles">Course</td>
    <td class="diamondTitles">Time</td>
    <td class="diamondTitles">Best Lap</td>
    <td class="diamondTitles">Machine</td>
    <td class="diamondTitles">Replay </td>
    <td class="diamondTitles">Rank</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="diamondTracks">Cosmo Terminal<br>- Trident - </td>
    <td class="diamondData">2'08"019</td>
    <td class="diamondData">40"224</td>
    <td class="diamondData">Gallant Star - G4</td>
    <td class="diamondData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="diamondData">20th</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="diamondTracks">Sand Ocean <br>- Lateral Shift - </td>
    <td class="diamondData">1'26"882</td>
    <td class="diamondData">25"401</td>
    <td class="diamondData">Fat Shark</td>
    <td class="diamondData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="diamondData">33rd</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<!--AX HMTL Table-->
  <table class="axTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="axHeader" colspan="6">AX Cup</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="axTitles">Course</td>
    <td class="axTitles">Time</td>
    <td class="axTitles">Best Lap</td>
    <td class="axTitles">Machine</td>
    <td class="axTitles">Replay </td>
    <td class="axTitles">Rank </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="axTracks">Lightning<br>- Thunder Road - </td>
    <td class="axData">2'48"170</td>
    <td class="axData">50"035</td>
    <td class="axData">Gallant Star - G4</td>
    <td class="axData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="axData">24th</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="axTracks">Green Plant<br>- Spiral - </td>
    <td class="axData">3'07"901</td>
    <td class="axData">56"641</td>
    <td class="axData">Quick Star - G4</td>
    <td class="axData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="axData">22nd</td>
  </tr>

</table>
---<!--End of Table-->---
    <hr>
    <footer>
      <strong>
                Copyright &copy; 2016 Stephen Fawcett, All rights reserved
        </strong>
    </footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #101010;
}

h2.main {
    font-size: 20px; 
    letter-spacing:1px; 
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #2050FF,
                -2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
                 2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
                -2px 2px 2px #2050FF,
                 2px 2px 2px #2050FF;"
}

#section {
    max-width: 960px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px;    
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#section2 {
    max-width: 1000px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px;    
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
    letter-spacing: 1px;

}

.main-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.wrapper {
  margin: 10px left;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}

   /*=====================
      Personal Bests CSS
    =====================*/

.TA{
    text-shadow:2px 3px 5px rgba(100,100,100,1);
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:2pt;
    font-size:22px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:impact, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
    margin:2px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding:0px;    
}

   /*===============
        Ruby CSS
    ==============*/

.rubyTable{ 
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-spacing:0;
     border-style: solid; 
     border-width: 4px;
     border-color: #4a4a4a;
     margin: 0px auto;
     margin-bottom:20px;
}

.rubyHeader{
    background-color:#7a0000;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:0pt;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:palatino linotype, palatino, serif;
    line-height:2;
    vertical-align:top;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.rubyTitles{
    background-color:#380000;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:3pt;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.rubyTracks{
    background-color:#120204;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 6px rgba(156,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#d1d1d1;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.rubyData{
    text-shadow:1px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
    background-color:#000000;

}

.rubyTable td{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.rubyTable th{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}



  /*===============
      Sapphire CSS
    ==============*/



.sapphireTable{
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-spacing:0;
     border-style: solid; 
     border-width: 4px;
     border-color: #4a4a4a;
     margin: 0px auto;
     margin-bottom:20px;
}   

.sapphireHeader{
    background-color:#00007a;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:0pt;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:palatino linotype, palatino, serif;
    line-height:2;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.sapphireTitles{
    background-color: #000038;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:3pt;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.sapphireTracks{
    background-color:#020412;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 6px rgba(0,0,156,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#d1d1d1;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.sapphireData{
    text-shadow:1px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
    background-color:#000000;
}

.sapphireTable td{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.sapphireTable th{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}




    /*===============
      Emerald CSS
    ==============*/



.emeraldTable{
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-spacing:0;
     border-style: solid; 
     border-width: 4px;
     border-color: #4a4a4a;
     margin: 0px auto;
     margin-bottom:20px;
}

.emeraldHeader{
    background-color:#036400;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:0pt;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:palatino linotype, palatino, serif;
    line-height:2;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.emeraldTitles{
    background-color:#003800;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:3pt;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.emeraldTracks{
    background-color:#041202;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 6px rgba(0,156,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#d1d1d1;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.emeraldData{
    text-shadow:1px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
    background-color:#000000;
}

.emeraldTable td{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.emeraldTable th{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}


    /*===============
      Diamond CSS
    ==============*/

.diamondTable{
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-spacing:0;
     border-style: solid; 
     border-width: 4px;
     border-color: #4a4a4a;
     margin: 0px auto;
     margin-bottom:20px;
}

.diamondTable td{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.diamondTable th{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}

.diamondHeader{
    background-color:#916c24;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:0pt;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:palatino linotype, palatino, serif;
    line-height:2;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.diamondTitles{
    background-color:#381c00;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:3pt;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.diamondTracks{
    background-color:#121002;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 6px rgba(156,156,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#d1d1d1;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.diamondData{
    text-shadow:1px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
    background-color:#000000;
}


    /*===============
         AX CSS
    ==============*/

.axTable{
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-spacing:0;
     border-style: solid; 
     border-width: 4px;
     border-color: #4a4a4a;
     margin: 0px auto;
     margin-bottom:20px;
}

.axTable td{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
    border: 1px solid purple;
}

.axTable th{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:11px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}   

.axHeader{
    background-color:#4e009c;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:0pt;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:palatino linotype, palatino, serif;
    line-height:2;
    vertical-align:top; 
}

.axTitles{
    background-color:#350069;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#eeeeee;
    letter-spacing:2pt;
    word-spacing:3pt;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.axTracks{
    background-color:#080212;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 6px rgba(78,0,156,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#d1d1d1;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
}

.axData{
    text-shadow:1px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:1pt;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:1;
    background-color:#000000;
}   






.tg .tg-mzmv{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#ff3838;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top
}
```

Please note that the only thing you should take note the account is under the CSS comment of "Personal Bests CSS".

Comment: Hey Stephen, welcome to SO! Please check out the guide to writing a great example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If you boil your code down to the most minimal HTML and CSS that preserves your problem, it'll help you pinpoint the problem and it will make it far easier for the rest of the community to figure out how to help. To start with, you can delete all the CSS before "personal bests css", but you could also make the tables much shorter, and remove any css that doesn't affect the problem (colors, fonts, text styles, probably even the padding). Takes a little time, but it's worth it :)

Comment: table{ width:800px; margin:auto; } 
add these lines to ur css code and you will get your answer. You can change width as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

> ```
> .rubyTable, .sapphireTable, .emeraldTable, .diamondTable, .axTable {
>     width: 90%;
>     margin: 0 auto;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To begin I think it could be a good idea to close your

```
<p class="TA"> with a </p>,
```

with that, you'll be at least try to test yours CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

To centre align a block level statically positioned object in CSS you can use `margin:auto;`

```
.rubyTable, .sapphireTable, .diamondTable {
    /* above; add whatever table class names you need */
    margin:auto;
}
```

NOTE: for clarity no top/bottom margin is specified in this shorthand version, but it's wise to read [the manual on Margin and shorthand CSS syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp).

Which automatically sets left and right margins to centre the object, in this case a table. As by default tables are block level elements its default width will be 100% so it's best to also set a width value here so that margin works on >0 values.

For example, to apply a set width as well as a set margin to ALL table objects, regardless of their class, you can use the table element type in your CSS:

```
table {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto; 
    min-width:300px; /* for mobile screens */
}
```

Note the above "table" reference does *not* have a full stop (`.`) preceeding it, meaning it is an element rather than a class rule.

---

### Repetitions:

As an extra piece I think from reading your question, You have a LOT of repetiton in your HTML code, for example:

```
 <table><tr><td class='rubyData'>text</td>
```

you have dozens of `rubyData` class name references in your HTML, but it can be much easier to assign these dynamically with CSS3 using the `direct decendent` syntax (`>`)

```
.rubyTable > tr:nth-of-type(1n+3) > td:first-of-type {
    /* this is the same as .rubyTrack CSS */
}
.rubyTable > tr:nth-of-type(1n+3) > td:not(:first-of-type) {
    /* this is the same as .rubyData CSS */
}
```

The first rule checks for the nth-of-type direct descendent (indicated by the `>` ) of the `.rubyTable` class, and finds each 1 occurrance from the 3rd of type.

Once that's established the rule then checks for the `first-of-type`, so that applies to the first `td` of the above definition.

Then it checks for all the other `td` that are `:not` first of type and applies different CSS to them.

```
<table class="rubyTable">
  <tr>
    <th class="rubyHeader" colspan="6">Ruby Cup</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Course</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Time</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Best Lap</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Machine</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Replay</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Rank</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td class="rubyTracks">Mute City<br>- Twist Road - </td>
    <td class="rubyData">53"699</td>
    <td class="rubyData">15"645</td>
    <td class="rubyData">Quick Star - G4</td>
    <td class="rubyData">Coming Soon</td>
    <td class="rubyData">46th</td>
  </tr>
```

Becomes:

```
<table class="rubyTable">
  <!-- // FIRST direct child occurance -->
  <tr> 
    <th class="rubyHeader" colspan="6">Ruby Cup</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- //SECOND tr occurance -->
  <tr> 
    <td class="rubyTitles">Course</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Time</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Best Lap</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Machine</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Replay</td>
    <td class="rubyTitles">Rank</td>
  </tr>
   <!-- //THIRD of type, so applies to this one and each 1 afterwards.  -->
  <tr> 
    <!-- //First occurance so applies that CSS -->
    <td>Mute City<br>- Twist Road - </td> 
    <!--  //not first so applies alternative CSS rule. -->
    <td>53"699</td>
    <td>15"645</td>
    <td>Quick Star - G4</td>
    <td>Coming Soon</td>
    <td>46th</td>
  </tr>
```

You see the third `<tr>` block is much tidier, smaller and more concise and easier to read as code.